# system index out of range c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a program which will figure out which half of an array added together is greater, however keep getting this error and I can not seem to figure out why

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Average Mark.exe" on line 31 when trying to work from the back of the array.

I am very new to c# and thought what I was doing should have worked?
Many thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace most_frequent_int
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            halfCheck(new int[] {1,1,2,3});
        }

        static void halfCheck(int[] checkArray)
        {
            int fHalf = 0; 
            int sHalf=0;

            //even method
            if (checkArray.Length % 2 == 0) 
            {               
                for (int i= 0;i<checkArray.Length/2;i++)//check first half even
                {
                    fHalf = fHalf + checkArray[i];
                }

                for (int i=checkArray.Length;i>checkArray.Length/2;i--)
                {
                    sHalf = sHalf + checkArray[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(sHalf);
                }

                if (fHalf > sHalf)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The first half is bigger");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The second half is bigger");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();

            }

            //odd method
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("odd");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: @Harvey Rush can you comment the line where the error is ocurring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it debug it and fix the error

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this code:

```
for (int i=checkArray.Length;i>checkArray.Length/2;i--)
{
    sHalf = sHalf + checkArray[i];
    Console.WriteLine(sHalf);
}
```

The `Length` property is 1-based, as it counts the elements in the array, but indexers are zero-based.  When you try to access `checkArray[i]`, the `i` value is past the end of the array.  Consider starting with `checkArray.Length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
for (int i = checkArray.Length; i > checkArray.Length / 2; i--)
```

You are assigning `i` to the array's length on the first iteration. You cannot index an array by its length, at it is one more than the last valid position.

Try this:

```
for (int i = checkArray.Length - 1; i > checkArray.Length / 2; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line:

```
 for (int i=checkArray.Length;i>checkArray.Length/2;i--)
```

The first element you access is `checkArray[checkArray.Length]` which is out of the array. The allowed indexes are to `checkArray.Length -1`.

Try with:

```
for (int i=checkArray.Length - 1; i > checkArray.Length/2; i-- )
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`for (int i=checkArray.Length;i>checkArray.Length/2;i--)`

Will throw an IndexOutofRangeException every time.  When using arrays, the `.length` property returns the number of elements in the array, which is NOT the same as the highest index.

For example, if `checkArray` has 5 elements, the indexes will be 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.  `checkArray.Length` will return the number of elements, which is 5.

Since your for loop begins with `i=checkArray.length`, the first index it tries will ALWAYS be out of bounds.  Try `i=checkArray.Length-1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change what i starts in the second loop.  i = checkArray.Length - 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace most_frequent_int
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     halfCheck(new int[] {1,1,2,3});
    }

    static void halfCheck(int[] checkArray)
    {
        int fHalf = 0; 
        int sHalf=0;

        //even method
        if (checkArray.Length % 2 == 0) 
        {               
            for (int i= 0;i<checkArray.Length/2;i++)//check first half even
            {
                fHalf = fHalf + checkArray[i];
            }

        for (int i=checkArray.Length - 1;i>checkArray.Length/2;i--)
            {
                sHalf = sHalf + checkArray[i];
                Console.WriteLine(sHalf);
            }

            if (fHalf > sHalf)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The first half is bigger");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The second half is bigger");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        //odd method
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("odd");
        }

    }

}
}
```

The array is indexed starting at 0 but length starts at 1.  So your array length is 4 and but checkArray[4] doesn't exist as the last item in the array is 3.  Length -1 should fix it.